# VBA replacement not working for specific input

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I am trying to make a VBA macro in excel which searches for a heading (succeeded at that), then selects the column of the heading (succeeded at that too) to finally do a replacement through the selected column (only partly succeeded in this).

I want to replace e.g SUM(C22:G22) with SUM(C22:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(); COLUMN()-1; 4))). It works just fine in excel when I select a column and then ctrl+H and find what :*) replace with :INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(); COLUMN()-1; 4))).

Below is the code I tried that works:

```
Sub FindString_Search_Replace_Column()
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Find(What:="XTOTAL 2021", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas2, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select
    Selection.Replace What:=":*)", Replacement:=":A3)", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
End Sub
```

It does exactly what I want when it "just" needs to replace with e.g. A3. However, when the code replacement bit gets a bit longer, see below code, with what I actually need, it seems like it stops right after `ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select`. It never actually changes anything.

```
Sub FindString_Search_Replace_Column()
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Find(What:="XTOTAL 2021", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas2, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select
    Selection.Replace What:=":*)", Replacement:=":INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(); COLUMN()-1; 4)))", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
End Sub
```

I am thinking it is the inside ADDRESS bit it kind of chokes on but here my google skills cannot help me any further (no results suiting my problem).

Any ideas? :)

Comment: To my knowledge Excel Replace does not support wildcards. Should that hold true, you have to loop though the relevant range cells and use the VBA Replace function on each one of them

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your answer. I think excel does support wildcards because like I said the first "dumbed" down bit of the code works just fine, where it's asked to replace :*) with just a simple :A3). No problems there. 
I am still a tad too new at VBA to know how to loop through the selected column but it might work.

Comment: Are you getting any error when you run your code?  Try removing the `FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2`

Comment: @TimWilliams, no not getting any error. It just stops at `ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select`, i.e. it has the entire column selected. I tried removing `FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2` like you prompted but it is the same result.

Comment: Maybe try replacing the `;` separators in your formula with `,` - when adding a formula in VBA typically you use "US-style" separator.  I don't know if that also applies to updating an existing formula.

Comment: @Tim, hallelujah, that worked!! Many thanks! :) Strangely, in the excel sheet it still uses `;` seperators despite the VBA having `,` seperators. This was good knowledge, thank you so much. How do I rate your comment to be the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the `;` separators in your formula with `,` - when adding a formula in VBA typically you use "US-style" separator (unless assigning the formula via `FormulaLocal`).

Possibly that also applies to updating an existing formula.